# Framing Mysql query based on json data coming to the server

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-2.7

Respected People,
I am having problem in handling JSON data sent to the server, using requests, as I am unable to frame the MySQL query.

```
{
  "Firsthouse": {
    "Doors": "10",
    "windows": "9"
   },     

  "Secondhouse": {
    "doors": "1",
    "windows": "10",
    "pools": "2"
   } 
}
```

This is how is I am processing the data on server:

```
request_data = request.get_json()
load_data = json.loads(request_data)
```

If the JSON were consistent wrt fields (like No "pools" in Firsthouse), I'd have the following query after some further processing:

```
for i in load_data:
    rows = i['doors'],i['windows'],i['pools']
    data_list.append(rows)

query = "insert into table (doors,windows,pools) values (%s,%s,%s)"
q_tup = data_list
cursor.executemany(query, q_tup)
```

But, the fields are not fixed in my JSON, there could be five max fields - doors, windows, pools, floors, chimneys.
Should I write 5 queries based on the presence of fields in JSON data, using If-else block ?
Many thanks for hint/ideas.

Comment: So yo uwill have to build the field list and the number of `%s` dynamically in a loop as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes Sir. 5 different data_list (field list) and 5 queries based on the number of fields present in JSON. Is that a correct approach?